# Prove that a set $\{\bot,\lor, \iff \}$ is functionally complete / incomplete

Tags: logic

We are just at the beggining of formal logic and we don't have any useful tools to prove such thing. We did only one example of proving functional incompleteness which consisted of looking at the truth table and saying something about the odd / even numbers of $T's$ and $F's$.

I was only able to break it down to:

Since $\{ \lnot, \lor \}$ is functionally complete and $\lor$ is in $\{\bot,\lor, \iff \}$, we only need to show that $\lnot$ cannot be expressed in terms of $\bot,\lor, \iff$.

Is there a straight-forward way for begginers to show such thing?

Comment: What is $ff$? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Always false statement. What's international notation? I'll edit it.

Comment: Maybe try $\bot$: `\bot`. Always false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, the problem is **incorrect**: $\neg a$ is equivalent to $a\iff\perp$. Since you have $\vee$ included explicitly, as you observe the functional completeness of $\{\vee,\neg\}$ translates to your set of connectives.

Comment: Oh, it's not an original text. I couldn't do it so I assumed it's not possible. I didn't now about a⟺⊥. My bad, sorry. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

But *are* those connectives functionally incomplete? Are you sure you can't define negation from them??

Consider the wff $(A \iff \bot)$.

What is its truth table?

How does it relate to the truth table for $\neg A$?